# Reporting Services Preview Processing Host Command Prompt Show Showing up

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

If I go to preview my report, immediately a command prompt shows up. ( a blank one ) 
This is how it [looks](http://prntscr.com/4fyxxl)
closing it will make me unable to preview any report until I unload-reload project /restart VS2013.
This is how the error  [looks like](http://prntscr.com/4fyyhg)after i close :

Comment: What does the reports data source look like?

Answer (score 1):

Due to not having comment privileges, posting as answer.
I am also having the same issue, @craig.white my data source is an embedded connection to a SQL server.  Authentication is via Windows Authentication.  The SQL Server is 2014 Developer Edition and I am using VS 2013 Ultimate edition.  The Window being open is an annoyance, but does not prevent working on the report, unless you close the window, then you cannot preview the report any further.  Please let me know if you require any more data.

Comment: We have the same issue, but I can still view my report even if I have that annoying console prompt.

Comment: I can still view the report as well, unless I close command window,  just like you.